# Is this a valid tensor representation of the Hodge star operation?

Tags: linear-transformations, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Since the Hodge star operation is a linear operation $*:\Lambda^kV \to \Lambda^{n-k} V$, then I thought that one could represent this linear map by tensor as one can can do for a linear map $A:V\to W$ by ${A^i}_j\ w_i\otimes v^j \in W\otimes V^*$, where $\{w_i\}$ resp. $\{v^j\}$ are basis of $W$ resp. dual basis of $V^*$.

So for an *orthonormal* basis $\{e_i\}$ of $V$ and and their algebraic dual $\{e^j\}$ in $V^*$, if we denote the basis $\{e_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_k}\}$ of $\Lambda^k V$ as $\{e_I\}$, and similarly for $\Lambda^{n-k} V^* \cong (\Lambda^{n-k} V)^*$ as $\{e^J\}$, where $I$ resp. $J$ are increaing $k$ resp. $n-k$ indices from $\{1,\dots,n\}$, we should get
$$
* = \sum_{I,J}\text{sgn}(I,J) \ e_I\otimes e^J \quad \in \quad(\Lambda^{n-k}V) \otimes (\Lambda^k V^*)
$$
where the permutation $(I,J)$ is the one that sends the first $k$ indices from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to $I$ and the rest to $J$. It is clear that the sum is only over $I$ and $J$ with $I\cap J = \emptyset$, or equivalently $I \cup J = \{1,\dots,n\}$.

In particular, for $k = 1$ we get the cross product of $n-1$ vectors in $\Lambda^1 V \cong V$, which lies in the space $\Lambda^{n-1}V$
$$
* = \sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j+1} e_j\otimes (e^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{e^j}\wedge\dots\wedge e^n)
$$
where a hat on an element means its absence. I hope that there is no mistake in this representation.

Comment: An important point here is that the Hodge star is defined only on a vector space with an inner product. Your formulas are correct only if the the bases are orthonormal. That’s also why there’s no simple formula.

Comment: Correct, thanks. I modified it.